# What is the meaning for a vector mod a matrix in a lattice?

Tags: lattice-crypto

I'm reading about the lattice recently.In the paper, it gives a method of a vector mod a matrix:

⃗c mod B as ⃗c−⌊⃗c×B^(−1)⌉×B = [⃗c×B^(−1)]×B.

I know that a integer A mod the other integer B is A+-kB, to make A in the defined field B.

Can anyone tell me what is the meaning of a vector mod a matrix and the mid term ⌊⃗c×B^(−1)⌉ means?:(

Tks.

Comment: I think this is the same question as http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29661/how-to-find-the-value-of-a-vector-modulo-a-basis-in-lattice-based-cryptography/29701#29701

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector u mod a matrix B is ​ u ± Bv . ​ ​ ​ We are [modding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group) an element of the vector space's

[additive group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_group) by the [range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(mathematics)) of the [restriction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)) of B to vectors whose entries are all integers.

The [parallelepiped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped) given by B's columns is a [fundamental domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain) for the range of that restriction.

⌊⃗c×B<sup>−1</sup>⌉ is probably [rounding each entry of c×B<sup>−1</sup> to the nearest integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer). ​ If that's correct, then they are using the [lattice representation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26897/991), which corresponds to using [the translation of the parallelepiped I mentioned which sends its center to the origin] as the fundamental domain.

Comment: well, i mean, we always mod the two same thing (like integer to integer), to get the answer. We use a vector mod a matrix to make the vector in the defined range, but now the range is a "matrix". i couldn't image how a matrix to be a "range", is it like a projection in a vector space or another thing?