# In DGHV FHE, why noise $r$ can be in $(-2^{\rho'}, 0)$?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

["Fully Homomorphic Encryption over the Integer"](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/146975/ihe.pdf) described a simple FHE scheme based on the GACD assumption. Its encryption function (on page 6) has the form $c \leftarrow (m + 2r + 2*\sum_{i \in S} x_i) \mod x_0$, where $\sum_{i \in S} x_i$ can be viewed as some ciphertexts of plaintext 0 (which can be divided by the secret key $p \in 2\mathbb{Z}+1$), and $r$, as the paper informed us, is randomly chosen from $(-2^{\rho'}, 2^{\rho'})$.

Decryption is taken by $m' = (c \mod p) \mod 2$.

It seems that "mod p" is used to drop $2*\sum_{i \in S} x_i$ and "mod 2" is used to drop $2r$.

If $r > 0$, the item $2r \mod p$ is even. It will not change the parity of $c \mod p$.

However, since $p$ is odd, for any $r < 0$, the item $2r \mod p$ in fact equals $p + 2r \mod p$, which is odd and will change the parity of $(c \mod p)$. I have programed for this algorithm and the result matchs the observation above.

What's the mistake of my reasoning and/or my understanding?

Comment: You are using a wrong [representation](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26897/991). ​ ​

Comment: In my opinion (and as the authors of the paper mentioned), here we do not need the knowledge of lattice (except the case to attack the scheme). The scheme itself is written in simple mathematics (though the proof is advanced). So just think about (elementary ) number theory, what's the mistake? Do you mean $(-2^{\rho'}, 2^{\rho'})$ is in fact $(0, 2^{\rho'+1})$?

Comment: In [that post](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26897/what-is-the-difference-between-the-standard-representants-of-mathbb-z-q-mathbb) tylo pointed out elements in lattices are not integers, but vectors. But here $r$ is 'verily' an integer...

Comment: The mistake is that you're just thinking about (elementary ) number theory, $\hspace{1.8 in}$ rather than using the symmetric representation. $\;$

Comment: As explained in my answer on the post that Ricky links to, for the "mod $p$" operation you need to return a representative between $-p/2$ and $p/2$, not $0$ and $p-1$.  This doesn't require any knowledge of lattices.

Comment: Well, can I shift the symmetric form to the normal form for programming easily?

Comment: Yes. ​ `((x+((p-1)/2))%p)-((p-1)/2)` ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Using the notation in the question, can I use $r \leftarrow (0, 2^{\rho'+1})$ instead of $r \leftarrow (-2^{\rho'},  2^{\rho'})$?

Comment: Yes, but that will produce ciphertexts with more noise without getting any security benefit from doing so.  Furthermore, the only way that can actually simplify things is if the noises for the $\hspace{1.31 in}$ modular reduction values use $\: r \leftarrow \left(\hspace{-0.03 in}-2^{\rho'+1}\hspace{-0.02 in},\hspace{-0.02 in}0\right) \;$. $\;\;\;\;$